# Scraping html with Python or

Tags: python, screen-scraping

One of the arguments I make to my (Microbiology and Genetics) students is that "data" is/are messy, and Python can help with that (of course other languages can too).  So here is a practical kind of web-based data-gathering exercise.

I notice that there a few people who answer Python-related questions among the users with the highest rep.  Among the questions which naturally arise:

I wish to recover the current rep and rate of rep increase for (top rated) Pythonistas on Stack Overflow, so as to predict whether or when [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli) will overtake [Steven Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott) or [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill)?  what about [Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph)?  Is it trivial because the increases for these guys are all pegged to the limit?

More generally, in the absence of an API for querying (which I don't think there is) is there any alternative to looking through the URLs of pages for patterns, loading those pages with Python and then scraping the html?  I realize there is probably not a general approach, but I'm interested in how people would approach this problem.

Edit:  @fitzgeraldsteele:  Generally.  SO is really just a (contrived) example.

Comment: Not sure what the question is here...Are you looking for how to screen scrape in general, or for stackoverflow specifically?

Comment: Apparently, there /was/ an API for this exact task (http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/101293-remove-100-post-limit-or-provide-way-to-view-them-all), but it seems to be broken now

Comment: Simply scraping and parsing with BeautifulSoup or regex would allow the whole project to be finished in a few hours.

Comment: @Max. S: Please post that as an answer so we can upvote it.

Comment: If you're asking about HTML scraping, this is an absolute duplicate.  All of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bhtml%5D+soup And no, Martelli may be thinner, smarter and better looking, but he'll never catch me.  I have long-running unit tests that give me too much "free" time while refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a perfectly usable monthly "data dump" of Stack Overflow under Creative Commons license, see for example [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-09/) (just the first one "under my thumb" of the many links about this -- at least one per month).  For such analysis as my average weekly rep relative to some other poster's, such monthly dollops of data are much more usable than screen-scrapes.

If you do want to screen-scrape some (other;-) site, and that doesn't violate their policies or their `robots.txt` files, Python is one of several excellent choices -- start with [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), and you won't have all that much extra work to do, for example.

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  Both scrapy and (even just the idea of) a monthly "data dump" are new to me.

Comment: They're both excellent ideas, especially the (Creative Commons license) data dump (there are reasons why SO became the leading programming Q&A site so rapidly -- great ideas behind it!-).